# Intermittent internet access issues over wi-fi with Apple Time Capsule and Netgear VDSL modem.

Tags: wireless-networking, airport

I've recently put my 3Tb current-gen Apple Time Capsule and Airport Express back into use with a new Netgear DM200 VDSL modem.

The configurations is as follows:

MODEM <-- Ethernet (30cm) --> TC <----- Ethernet (15m) ------> AEX

The Airport Express is there to provide wi-fi access to a room that get a very poor wi-fi signal.

The TC is in bridge mode as is the AEX, which is configured via Airport Utility to extend the WiFi from the TC.

However, all wireless clients intermittently (about 50% of the time) get the problem of being connected to WiFi but not getting any internet access. In fact, the 'WiFi' settings screen of a connected device (iPhone, Mac, Win10 PC)explicitly states 'No Internet'.

This can be fixed by either switching Wi-Fi off and on or by switching to/from the 5Ghz network. This might work after 1 attempt or 10.

I've tried not having guest network, not having the 5Ghz network, disconnecting the AEX or switching the AEX and the TC, in case it's the TC's Wi-Fi that's the problem. Nothing seems to work.

It's as though on occasion the 'bridge' between the WiFi and the modem is not working. although some wireless clients might be working whilst others aren't.

The problem appears to only manifest itself or clear upon joining the WiFi network - if it's working, it stays working.

Wired connections are fine.

I've also tried the modem in 'modem only' mode (as opposed to 'modem+router') but it didn't make any difference.

Any ideas? I'm assuming that because it's capable of working, and not restricted to just the TC or AEX, then it's a configuration issue, and something that the Airport Utility's configuration wizard isn't getting right.

Comment: You should have a router in there somewhere... When you say that the Time Capsule is in "_bridge mode_", I suspect it is not acting as a router... If you are in fact using the Time Capsule as the router, then please ensure that the modem is connected to the "WAN" port.

Comment: Please share the IP address that your devices receive (to confirm above)

Comment: You should not connect a PC directly to the modem - you must have a router in place.

Comment: @Attie By default the modem is in 'modem+router' mode and the TC was set to 'Bridge' mode, so I think DHCP and NAT are being done by the modem. I suspect the IP addresses are wrong somewhere but bear in mind that switching WiFi networks (WiFi is provided only by the TC or AEX) will eventually get a connections. When I get home I'll see if I can provide a better network map with IP addresses, default gateways etc.